# could not resolve placeholder as system property: neither system property nor environment variable found

Tags: java, spring

Could not resolve placeholder 'server.conf' in `file:///${server.conf}/his-config.properties` as system property: neither system property nor environment variable found

his-config-spring.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                   
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">



 <bean id="placeholderConfig"
    class="com.napier.core.boc.spring.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurater">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:///${server.conf}/his-config.properties</value>
            <!-- <value>classpath:his-config.properties</value> -->
        </list>
    </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: And your question is???

Comment: What type of configuration, need to write, Why I am getting this error while property file is fetching from outside. But how can i resolve by putting that property file into my classpath.. How to configure in "placehoderConfig" bean and its respective property name "locations" for "his-config.properties" file. still require to clarify my Question. Might be I am asking wrong Q. but I am facing this

Comment: @Jeet you have given us very little details. Spring needs to actually load some properties before you can use them. Also - do you actually use Spring 2.5 (spring-tx-2.5.xsd) ??

Comment: Yes I am using spring 2.5